# What synchronization issue does the following JAVA code suffer from?

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

The author of [this page](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week11/22.html) mentions that the second code example below suffers from a synchronization problem but the code will work about 99 times in 100. I am not able to see the operational difference in the two programs in that page.

---

A somewhat more general solution that combines the previous two is to copy the value of the field into a local variable, then change only the local variable. The field remains unchanged inside the method. For example,

```
public class Counter {

  int count = 0;

  public void count() {
    int count = this.count;
    int limit = count + 100;
    while (count++ != limit) System.out.println(count); 
  }

}
```

Note how the local variable count shadows the field count, and how the this keyword is used to refer to the field count outside the shadow.

This trick is primarily useful when you don't need to save the changed variable back into the field when the method is done. The following saves the state, but is still subject to less obvious synchronization problems.

```
public class Counter {

  private int count = 0;

  public void count() {
    int count = this.count;
    int limit = count + 100;
    while (count++ != limit) System.out.println(count);
    this.count = count; 
  }

}
```

In fact, this is probably even worse than the original example because it will work 99 times out of a 100. The bug here is extremely hard to pin down if you don't spot it in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that the modification to `this.count` is not atomic.

Let's say two threads are calling this function and `this.count` is currently set to `0`.

Thread 1 loads `0` into its local `count` and then starts incrementing it to `101` (not `100` as previously thought since it increments `count` one more time after the limit is reached, with `count++ != limit`).

In the meantime, thread 2 comes in and `this.count` is *still* set to `0` so it grabs it and starts incrementing to `101`.

At some point, they then both reach the line `this.count = count` (and the order doesn't matter) and they *both* set `this.count` to 101.

What it *should* have been set to at the end was `202` (I think - certainly it should be around the `200` mark somewhere).

The reason the first bit of code is valid is because it's not actually trying to change the `this.count` value hence no race condition is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If this is the issue the author means, then this should be occurring most of the times since most of the times, the second thread would start before the first has finished. However, the author says that the program works 99 times out of 100. So I am not sure if the intended value of this.count is 200 at the end of the program.

Comment: "the second thread would start before the first has finished" is very much an untested assertion. In fact, I'd be surprised if creating another thread of execution were faster than a 100-iteration loop. I'd suggest running it to test. Of course, the author's assertion of a 99% success rate may also be hyperbole :-)

Comment: @BM: I couldn't find any other issue in this code, especially if you take a look at the next page, where author suggests a use od `synchronized` keyword on the entire method as one of the possible solutions to that problem.

Comment: I ran the code several times and also printed the value of this.count at the end. On most occassions I got 101. On a few occassions I got 201. But either way, the output of the program being indeterminate is not a desirable solution.

Comment: There you go then, hyperbole it was :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comments. Thank you @Crozin as well.